# Drawable xml with horizontal line and circle in middle

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I want to create a drawable xml file for the shape below. It will be like a horizontal line should fill the width of the layout and a circle in the middle.

[image]

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: see my answer below drwable xml is exactly drawing according your image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keep it simple

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:height="1dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="56dp"
        android:height="56dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply and it works as I need. How can I get rounded curve at the start and end of the line?

Comment: @Kameswari to achieve that, instead of the single item that defines the oval shape with center gravity, you should have two items. set the gravity of the first one to "left" and set the gravity of second one to "right".

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtstep"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/simple_border_white"
                android:textSize="3dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/round_with_shadow"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="26sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

simple_border_white.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <!--background color of box-->
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/accentcolor" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

round_with_shadow.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/accentcolor"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="@color/colorPrimaryLight"/>
    <size android:width="40dp" android:height="40dp"/>
</shape>
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Create your drawable file and put below code.
And change your color code red.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:bottom="10dp"
    android:left="10dp"
    android:right="10dp"
    android:top="10dp">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        <size
            android:width="10dp"
            android:height="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="180"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="90">
        <shape
            android:shape="line"
            android:top="1dp">
            <stroke
                android:width="0.5dp"
                android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use below `drawable` XML into your views background :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
            <!--background color of box-->
        </shape>

    </item>
    <item
        android:height="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
            <!--background color of box-->
        </shape>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attributes `height` and `width` in `<item/>` are supported since 23 api.
For earlier versions you can use following code:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:gravity="center">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:height="1dp" />
        <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:gravity="center">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size
            android:width="30dp"
            android:height="30dp" />
        <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
    </shape>
</item>
```